# How to use Expo SDK without using XDE or expo mobile app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to use only the expo SDK in my react project and I don't need XDE or anything else.  When I installed EXPO thorough npm and imported it to my react native project and ran the project it gave me this error message:

> Internal server error: 500.

I want to know if there is a way to use only expo SDK in my project without going to expo environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use the Expo SDK without the Expo client, but you will need to use `exp` or `XDE` still (so `exp start` rather than `react-native start`). This may change, we haven't explored the space of integrating into existing native apps too much yet. The only documented way to get this set up will be hard to work with if you have a large existing app that you want to integrate the SDK into. You will need to [follow this guide](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v18.0.0/guides/detach.html) to "detach" an Expo project, so it generates the Android/iOS project files for you, then build your project on that. Feel free to open a feature request at https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests if you have specific parts you'd like to change for this.